# How to reorder stacked bargraph from largest percent difference between groups to least percent difference?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

Does anyone know how to reorder the stacked bargraph above so it goes from biggest percent difference between blue and red to least percent difference?

I tried reorder(), but not sure what the logic would be to make it work as I want it.

This is an example of the data

| text_idx | label_name | user_email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | agentic | email 1 |
| 1 | agentic | email 2 |
| 2 | communal | email 1 |
| 3 | communal | email 2 |

This is the code I'm using:

`table<-data%>%group_by(user_email)%>%count(label_name)`

`ggplot(table, aes(x=label_name, y=n, fill=user_email))+ geom_bar(stat="identity")+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))`

Comment: Create a new variable with the value of the percentage difference and use it as an argument on the reorder function. reorder(your_variable_on_x_axis, your_new_variable). If you provide a dataset example and share your code would be much easier to help.

Comment: I provided the dataset and code. Having a difficult time mapping the computed differences to the correct label_name